# Which CPUs support TSX, with the erratum fixed?

Tags: cpu

With the discovery of [a bug](http://techreport.com/news/26911/errata-prompts-intel-to-disable-tsx-in-haswell-early-broadwell-cpus) in the implementation of [TSX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions), all CPUs designed before that discovery have the extension disabled via microcode.

Half a year later, I haven't found much about new steppings of broadwell that fix the erratum.  wikipedia's TSX article says "The bug was fixed in F-0 steppings of the vPro-enabled Core M-5Y70 Broadwell CPU in November 2014", with a link to http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/core-m-processor-family-spec-update.pdf.

I also found an article saying that [Xeon D CPUs will have usable TSX](http://www.theplatform.net/2015/03/09/intel-crafts-broadwell-xeon-d-for-hyperscale/), and that TSX will be available in the upcoming “Haswell-EX” Xeon E7 processors, according to one of Intel's CPU designers.

So the question: which currently available CPUs have a fixed implementation of TSX?  Especially, any CPUs that could be put into a budget desktop (not Xeons), but answers detailing which mobile, embedded, system-on-chip, and workstation / server Xeon CPUs have a production-safe TSX implementation are welcome.

BTW, I know TSX is only going to give speedups of a couple % at best on most things.  I'm mostly interested for future-proofing, since software might start to make more use of parallelism for things where locking overhead was a killer without TSX.

Also, I couldn't find any definitive answer to when fixed steppings of CPUs will become available, so the Internet is in need of having this information all in one place.

Comment: You have basically listed those that do.  This seeens to close to a hardware shopping question

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking.  Is there a different stackexchange site that's more appropriate?  Should I edit my question to take out the ones I've found so far, and move that to an answer?  I'm asking because I don't 100% trust what I've found so far, and I haven't found any authoritative info on when new steppings of existings chips might come out, or already are out.

Comment: Neither of the two pages I found mentioned the other, so that's why I wanted to collect things in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update on this: [HLE is disabled on all current CPUs because of the TAA vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310108/has-hardware-lock-elision-gone-forever-due-to-spectre-mitigation).  RTM is still usable on CPUs that didn't have it disabled because of bugs, if the OS doesn't disable it.

---

- Haswell Xeon E7 series [supports TSX](http://techreport.com/news/28225/xeon-e7-v3-boasts-haswell-cores-hybrid-memory-controller).  This is the Haswell-EX core, for servers with more than 2 sockets.  (Haswell-EP is the up-to-dual socket part, and has broken TSX.)
- Xeon D (low-power Broadwell) has [working TSX](http://www.theplatform.net/2015/03/09/intel-crafts-broadwell-xeon-d-for-hyperscale/).
- Desktop Broadwell has working TSX [on the 5775C part with eDRAM](http://ark.intel.com/products/88040/Intel-Core-i7-5775C-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz?q=Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A2%20i7-5775C%20Processor%20%286M%20Cache,%20up%20to%203.70%20GHz%29).
- Skylake has working TSX.

---

- Haswell and Haswell-EP have broken TSX.  AFAICT, fixed steppings do not exist.
- All mobile Broadwell parts have broken TSX,  AFAICT.